# how to make a file/folder hidden/unhidden in J2ME

Tags: java-me

Currently am working on a project where I need to hide my files/folder on sd card..?? I was wondering is it possible to hide and then latter unhide a file/folder..?? I got this from searching which helps you to create a text file in Images under Gallery

```
 import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.io.file.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WriteMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
private TextBox textbox;
private String photos = "fileconn.dir.photos";
private Command saveCommand;
private Command exitCommand;
private String path;

public void startApp() {
    textbox = new TextBox("WriteMIDlet", "", 1000, TextField.ANY);
    saveCommand = new Command("Save", Command.SCREEN, 1);
    exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
    textbox.addCommand(saveCommand);
    textbox.addCommand(exitCommand);
    textbox.setCommandListener(this);
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(textbox);
    path = System.getProperty(photos);
}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

private void saveFile(String path, String name) {
    try {
        String url = path + name;
        String string = textbox.getString();
        byte data[] = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
        FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        if (!fconn.exists()) {
            fconn.create();
        }
        OutputStream ops = fconn.openOutputStream();
        ops.write(data);
        ops.close();
        fconn.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException: "+ioe.getMessage());
    }
    catch (SecurityException se) {
        System.out.println("Security exception:" + se.getMessage());
    }
} 

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
    if (c == saveCommand) saveFile(path, "readme.txt");
    if (c == exitCommand) this.notifyDestroyed();
}
```

}

Like wise is there any way we could create a folder in sd card and then hide/unhide it according to need..?? Also can we retrieve hidden folders ..??

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
fconn.setHidden(true);
```

but... according to documentation:

> The attribute is applied to the file on the actual file system
>   immediately upon invocation of this method if the file system and
>   platform support it. **If the file system doesn't support a hidden
>   attribute, this method is ignored and isHidden() always returns false**.

Comment: thank you it worked.. but setting the value as false doesnt make it visible again..I tried setting true and false to setHidden() when true the text file is hidden but when set false I am not able to view it again.. do you know why..??

Comment: Good to know that you could set the file hidden. I do not know why the opposite (setHidden(false)) did not work. :(